# More concise way of inserting a character between all characters in a string

Tags: ruby, coding-style

I want to insert a character at every possible index of a string, including before the first element and after the last. Right now I'm doing:

```
      result = []
      result << c + str
      result << str + c
      for i in 0..str.length-2 do
        result << (str[0..i] + c + str[i+1..-1])
      end
```

Is there  a way of doing this without having 2 special cases and having a loop from 0 to `str.length - 2`

**EDIT**

Sample output with '-' and 'hello':

```
["-hello", "h-ello", "he-llo", "hel-lo", "hell-o", "hello-"]
```

Comment: Do you want to interleave them essentially?

Comment: what output do you want? `["-hello", "h-ello", "he-llo", "hel-lo", "hell-o", "hello-"]` or `"-h-e-l-l-o-"`. Your code points to 1, your words to 2.

Comment: You should provide sample input and output instead of just your solution and a description.

Answer (score 6):

I'll assume you want `["-hello", "h-ello", "he-llo", "hel-lo", "hell-o", "hello-"]`, your question is not clear.

```
s = "hello"
(0..s.size).map { |i| s.clone.insert(i, "-") }
#=> ["-hello", "h-ello", "he-llo", "hel-lo", "hell-o", "hello-"]
```

For those that prefer a functional approach (I do):

```
(0..s.size).map { |i| (s[0...i] + "-" + s[i..-1]) }
#=> ["-hello", "h-ello", "he-llo", "hel-lo", "hell-o", "hello-"]
```

Comment: +1, I think this is what the OP wants. This is what I get for inferring sample input/output from the title/description rather than running their code…

Comment: I'm impressed that you knew this is what the answer was supposed to be without sample output.

Comment: @squiguy: No black magic, I just run the code provided in the answer and something similar to this output came out. Priti: People in SO seem to prefer a full answer, not just pointers to the answer, if that's good or bad I don't know :-) I added also a FP implementation, I don't like imperative solutions (unless performance is a problem).

Comment: @tokland I have a ready made good answer for this, I didn't post it as the `OP` didn't provide any examples. I don't have like you a guess power :). But it's OK. Carry on, will meet you in coming posts,Here I will not post the answer I do have for the same,which is more shorter than you, as to my pointer answer at that situation no one supported me. :(

Comment: @priti: this is the 3 or 4 time I've seen you criticize whomever submitted the accepted answer.

Comment: @messick Yes! that's with proper reason, If you see me 3-4 times,obviously you had noticed why I did. So no more argue please. FYI the count is 1 or 2 times, I think.

Comment: Complaining that the community upvoted/accepted another answer besides your own does not constitute a "proper" reason.